# Which of these is the correct way to encode a type III ANOVA analysis?

Tags: regression, anova, interaction, contrasts

I am trying to run a type III ANOVA analysis to look at how the three factors A, B and C affect the continuous variable X. Online I have found two ways of encoding the model which give different results and p-values.

The first is this:

```r
model1 <- lm(X ~ A*B*C, data = dataset)
summary(model1)
library(car)
Anova(model1, contrasts=list(A=contr.sum, B=contr.sum, C=contr.sum), 
      type=3)

Anova Table (Type III tests)

Response: X
                         Sum Sq  Df  F value    Pr(>F)    
(Intercept)             1956.03   1 262.5421 < 2.2e-16 ***
A                        202.93   4   6.8095 2.635e-05 ***
B                       1975.67   1 265.1793 < 2.2e-16 ***
C                          3.53   1   0.4744   0.49140    
A:B                      124.31   4   4.1713   0.00255 ** 
A:C                       14.66   4   0.4921   0.74157    
B:C                       26.60   1   3.5702   0.05957 .  
A:B:C                     22.54   4   0.7563   0.55431    
Residuals               2898.18 389                       
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

The second is this:

```r
type3 <- list(A = contr.sum, B = contr.sum, C = contr.sum)
model1.5 <- lm(X ~ A*B*C, data = dataset, contrasts = type3)
Anova(model1.5, type = 3)

Anova Table (Type III tests)

Response: X
                        Sum Sq  Df    F value    Pr(>F)    
(Intercept)             129787   1 17420.2878 < 2.2e-16 ***
A                         1595   4    53.5251 < 2.2e-16 ***
B                        24284   1  3259.4878 < 2.2e-16 ***
C                          435   1    58.3535 1.720e-13 ***
A:B                        226   4     7.5987 6.666e-06 ***
A:C                         30   4     1.0088 0.4026915    
B:C                        101   1    13.5974 0.0002587 ***
A:B:C                       23   4     0.7563 0.5543089    
Residuals                 2898 389                         
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Would anyone be able to tell me what the difference is between these two methods and whether or not one is preferable/ correct.

Comment: `car::Anova` ignores the `contrasts` argument, so the second method is the way to calculate Type III sums of squares. Please see the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/car/versions/3.1-2/topics/Anova).